# Unable to Disable Browser Back button on some devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-4, browser-history

I am working on an application where I want user to continue without clicking back button. I want to prevent them to go back and perform same task again and if they click back button then display a popup message with bootstrap modal.

Here is my code snippet.

```
function showPopup(url, valid_device) {
  if (window.history && window.history.pushState) {
    $(window).on('popstate', function() {
      $('#bckBtnModal').modal('show');
    });

    $(window).on('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
      $('#bckBtnModal').modal('show');
    });
  }
}

function moveForward(url){
  window.history.pushState( 'forward', null, url );
  history.forward()
}

function checkState(url, valid_device){
  if (window.history && window.history.pushState) {
    window.history.pushState({},'forward', null, url);
    $(window).on('popstate', function() {
      $('#bckBtnModal').modal('show');  
  });
  $(window).on('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    if(valid_device && show_on_dom_event && push_state_enable){
      $('#bckBtnModal').modal('show');
    }
  });
 }
}
```

I have used above function like given below:

```
window.onpageshow = BackBtnHandler.showPopup('/reservations/guest_party_details', '<%= valid_device?%>')
window.onnavigate = BackBtnHandler.moveForward('/reservations/guest_party_details');
```

But it is not global solution, I found that on OSx chromium browser when page loaded two functions called because it fires two event `popstate`, `DOMContentLoaded` while the other most of the browsers either calls `popstate` or `DOMContentLoaded`.

I have also tried history.js but didn't get any useful from it.

Anyone have any global solution which works for all major browsers and for all major Operating systems?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but it seems like something any decent browser would absolutely **not** allow you to do. Maybe consider *why* you need to prevent this behaviour. Is it because the form won't cope with going back? Then detect that and redirect them forward or allow the form to cope.

Comment: I have a reservation flow  and payment flow in my application, I don't want user to go back and reserve or pay for same thing. BTW Thanks for response.

Comment: There's things you can do to avoid this, perhaps have the form in a modal which won't change the browser history, or open the form in a new tab which will reset the history.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29986657/global-variable-usage-on-page-reload/